# How to notify the user of a system error (out of their control)?

Tags: copywriting, error-message

What's an easy-to-understand error message for situations where the error is a system error (out of the control of the user and cannot be fixed by the user)?

Here's a few that I came up with, but it's hard to tell what works well:

- A system error has occurred and the action you have requested could not be completed. (too vague, does not let the user know they cannot fix it).
- There was a problem (action) your (object) and it is beyond your control. (makes the user feel helpless).

Any suggestions as to the best way to word such a message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MailChimp has some advice on writing a failure message in their [Voice & Tone](http://voiceandtone.com/failure-message) guide.

> - Be straightforward. Explain what's going on right away. Be calm.
> - Don’t use exclamation points or alarming words like “alert” or "immediately."
> - Be serious. Don’t joke around with frustrated people.
> - If possible, offer a solution or next step.

They included a generic, example error message, but it really depends on what went wrong (or how much the system knows about what went wrong) and whether a next step can be offered to the user (e.g., restart the app, browse the archives, request an email when we're back online).

Comment: I found out about it from Rahul in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/user-experience).

Answer (score 2):

I think here you can find the answer to your question: [Stackoverflow - How does one write good error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194537/how-does-one-write-good-error-messages)

My main points are (in case of a system for IT guys):

- admit that it is the systems fault, never say that the user did something wrong
- provide possible solution
- offer some help
- offer the opportunity to send the error message/description

But really, **it depends on the users of the system** - who is it for?

Is it for financial people? Is it for marketing experts? Is it for IT faces? Is it for young people? Always consider the living **language of your users**, and phrase your sentence accordingly.

Comment: As of today, the link you mention has been taken off Stack Overflow. Kt takes you to a page that says it's been taken off because of reasons of moderation. But otherwise good advice!!